# If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^3 = O_{3}$, show that $I - A$ is invertible with inverse $I + A + A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

So this question is basically a proof.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix (so square) which satisfies the condition $A^3 = O_{3}$ ($A^{3}$ gives the $3 \times 3$ zero matrix), then show that $(I - A)$ is invertible with inverse $(I + A + A^2)$.

I have no idea where to start, all help welcome.

Comment: What can you say in the general case $A^m=0$ ?

Comment: That it is m is the nilpotent index of A? I answered the question already, but I want to know if that is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Sure, you can take $m$ to be the smallest such exponent.

Comment: What were you going for when you asked? What I mean is, what other assumption can be made?

Comment: I meant, when $A^m=0$, what is the inverse of $I-A$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: for any invertible matrix $A$ with inverse $A^{-1}$, we have $AA^{-1} = I$. Try multiplying out $(I-A)(I+A+A^{2})$. You should get some cancellation and then use your condition to conclude something...

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help! :)